# What is a pandas dataframe label?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking at pandas for the first time and I'm going through the '10 minutes to pandas' tutorial. I've come [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#selection-by-label) . I've checked through [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) , but I'm still not clear on what a label is. Can someone explain ?

Answer (score 1):

"Selection by label" just is just another way of saying selection by the value. So for example, if you had a dataframe with a datetime index and you wanted the first date you could do:

```
df.iloc[0]
```

to get the first row. But if you wanted to select a specific date, you would select by label (or you could say by value)

```
df.loc["2016-12-31"]
```

And this would return the row corresponding to the point in the index where "2016-12-31" is present. Note the "df.loc" rather than "df.iloc" because it's selection by label and not selection by index

Comment: when you say ' selection by the value' do you mean 'selection by the value of the index'?